# Hide unsupported character in textbox

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

Hide unsupported text from text box if font not supported.
I have added one textbox and applied one font and added some text, numbers and special characters, a-z character shows perfectly but number and special characters show in default browser supported fonts. I have attached screen shot for the same.

1. Original font rendering
   [image: Original font rendering]
2. Rendering on canvas
   [image: Canvas Rendering]

Comment: do you want to block people from adding numbers and special characters to the textarea?

Comment: no i just want to hide or remove that character which is not supported by fonts

Answer (score 5):

You can use blank font to as a fallback font:

```css
span {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: red;
}

.actual {
  font-family: 'Shizuru';
}

.blank {
  font-family: 'Shizuru', 'AdobeBlank';
}

    @font-face {
      font-family: AdobeBlank;
      src:
        url("data:font/opentype;base64,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");
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shizuru&text=ABCD" rel="stylesheet">
<div>Actual  : <span class='actual'>ABCD1234ABCD</span></div>
<div>Blanked : <span class='blank'>ABCD1234ABCD</span></div>
```

In above example I am using Shizuru as main font imported from googlefonts. Using the url `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shizuru&text=ABCD` I am getting only `ABCD` characters from the googlefonts. So remaining characters are displayed using fallback font by the browsers.

But if we use a blank font, like [AdobeBlank](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/adobe-blank), as a fallback then extra characters won't be displayed. AdobeBlank is non-spacing blank font. You can use spacing blank font if you wish to have blank spaces for non displayed characters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: Hi onkar ruikar, AdobeBlank font working perfect but not able to find blank spacing font. Can you please help me to find font which make space if font fallback

Comment: Unless the font is monospace each character has different width e.g. w is wider than l. To keep whitespaces consistent you need to generate the blank font from your main/primary font. I have no idea about font generation. You can refer to https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/25820/167550 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58643 . You may ask question there. There is a [no-def font](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/adobe-notdef/blob/master/cidfont.ps). That has only one character you can replace it with blank and recompile. I couldn't find readymade blank spacing font either.